# Выбрать элементы с динамически добавленными классами

Tags: html, jquery

Помогите не могу получить элементы с классом "d-none"...
Есть список, некоторые элементы ранее динамически получили класс "d-none".

```
<ul>
    <li>Тест</li>
    <li>Тест</li>
    <li class="d-none">Тест</li>
    <li class="d-none">Тест</li>
</ul>
```

Такой конструкцией пытаюсь получить эти элементы:

```
$("ul > li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("d-none")) {
        console.log("Нашел");
    } else {
        console.log("Не нашел");
    }
});
```

Но в консоли выдает только "Не нашел", в чем может быть проблема?

Если в цикле просто вставить

```
console.log($(this));
```

То там динамические классы у двух элементов видно... не пойму в чем дело...

Comment: В какой момент вы выполняете js цикл — уже после добавления нужных классов элементам? Раз `$("ul > li")` не находит их, значит во время выполнения цикла класс не добавлен.

Comment: Угу, цикл выполняю после добавления классов. Если в этом цикле указать console.log($(this)), то в консоли видно, что у двух элементов есть класс...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
      <li>Тест</li>
      <li>Тест</li>
      <li class="d-none">Тест</li>
      <li class="d-none">Тест</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="res" id="res">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#res").click(function(){
        $("ul > li").each(function(){
          if ($(this).hasClass("d-none"))alert("has");
          else alert("no has");
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Hochru у вас вроде бы все верно, может ошибку стоит поискать в другом месте?